# Using checkbox in a recycler view row causes the row to not display all its content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recycler view row layout below. The recycler view is used without particular attribute.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My 2 lines texts are cut in height when the checkbox is used in the layout and displayed entirely when the checkbox is removed ???

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#484848"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/firstTV" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```